# Is there a Facebook messenger app

Tags: facebook

I am looking for desktop application for Facebook messenger. I know Pidgin can work with Facebook chat, but it cannot work with any messenger with a person who is offline. Is there a program which can do this?

Comment: According to [fb messenger API being disabled march 2014](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/fbmessenger-stand-alone-facebook.html) the fbmessenger app on windows and linux wil no longer work after that date

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know if you're still looking, but here's your answer. It's not an official Facebook app, but I use it every day and I love it.

[image]
[Here is the link to the site I used to download it](https://messengerfordesktop.com/)

Comment: I really never understood people using apps that acts like browser of specific page.
In app description it says that is uses facebook site messenger.com and just acts like browser. If so, then the same amount of resources we use when we go to messenger.com is used when using the app. My thought are that purpose of using an app is less-resource consuming than using it in browser. Which in this case, isn't.

Comment: Where did the Ubuntu installation go ? I don't see it in site ?

Answer (score 7):

## General way

So what about **Empathy**[image: installit] ?
Usually empathy is installed in Ubuntu when it comes. But if no go ahead install it [from here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/empathy/). Or just click button

[image: download button]
[image]

> Note you can't write to offline person. But I think if you will have conversation already opened you can.

### Alternative way

So here is alternative way: **integrating facebook chat with firefox**, read more [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/firefox-17-arrives-with-facebook-integration-baked-in)
**And** install plugin from [here](https://www.facebook.com/about/messenger-for-firefox)
[image: facebook in firefox]

Comment: Like pidgin, its based on an IM paradigm. I'm looking for a 'Facebook Messenger' paradigm (like the app). In this, it is based around my conversations, not who is online at the moment. If I click on a person it doesn't show my recent history and I pretty sure that since Facebook messages aren't chat, it doesn't handle them.

Comment: uhm, @superbriggs what about integrating with firefox ? i.e. look at edit

Comment: I try to connect to FB with Pidgin and Empthy after every update. But they never seem to work for me.

Comment: haha, well sad actually, report a bug ?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes there is !**

Here is an "un-official official facebook messenger" app.

[image]

**You can download from here:
http://messengerfordesktop.com**

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be something interesting going on here: http://messengerfordesktop.com/#download

Actually it's just an unofficial desktop wrapper over this site: https://www.messenger.com/login/#

Still it's kinda nice to have that as a separate window.

Comment: using a whole tab as separate browser window will suffice

Answer (score 2):

If you're still interested, I think I found a solution. Open the https://www.messenger.com site on Chrome or Chromium, the same site which the above-mentioned app (which is somewhat unreliable) is just a wrapper for. Then you click on the top right options in Chromium, select more **Tools** -> **Add site to Desktop**.

Then if you search your launcher, there'll be a web app called 'Messenger' which loads up exactly what you're looking for. It's basically the original Chromium page but without any toolbars, very minimalist ...

Comment: Very good suggestion it was. I think, i better stick with this instead of another bloaty electron-based browser-page-turned-app

Answer (score 2):

For me the best alternative for now is Franz:

http://meetfranz.com/

It is a cross-platform program and supports many other messengers.